# Decide the count of nodes to be setup

Tags: nodes

This is in context of private blockchain setup.

In a business scenario there are lets say three\four category of parties. Now among these categories two of them are having quite a good number of parties. Lets say 10k parties under each of these two categories. Each party is having their own list of users.

What should be the criteria for deciding how many nodes are required. What kind of benefits one can think for owning a node. Is it preferable to have at-least one mining node for each transaction node.

Is there any technical constraint to keep in mind while deciding about the count of nodes which should be present?

It will be great if you please share your views.